# Elastic Cloud APM not showing logs in Transactions log Page

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, apm

[image]

How to makes Kibana to show logs in APM "Transactions" page under "Logs" tab. I verified the logs are successfully being generated with the "trace.id",but i have no idea how to setup to hit here my log
[image]

Comment: Have you created data view or index pattern in Kibana ?

Comment: Hi is there any specific documents for add spring log4j logs into that?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/logs.html

Comment: Check above link and see whether APM agent that you configured is sending logs in the first place to Elastic Search or not..

Access Elastic Search indices endpoint to check whether index is created and it is able to add documents to that index... If Elastic search has this information...

I am assuming, It won't be kibana issue.. It could be agent failing to publish data to Elastic Search.